# Java Google Drive API Error

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to download files using google drive API using the code

```
 private static void downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {

        //String fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            service.files().export(file.getId(), "application/pdf")
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Each time I am getting this Error:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403

    Forbidden
    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
       }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Insufficient Permission"
     }
    }

            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1070)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpDownloader.java:245)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:199)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:562)
            at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Export.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(Drive.java:3402)
            at Quickstart.downloadFile(Quickstart.java:162)
            at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:130)
```

Do anyone has any idea where I am doing wrong?

Comment: The clue is "Insufficient Permission". It's self-explanatory.

Comment: But how to resolve this is an issue?

Comment: It's a bit like saying how to resolve "invalid password". Your application doesn't have permission to read that file. That's all.

Comment: Scope has been set as  private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE); which gives full access. Still i am facing this error for all the file for which this method is called.

Comment: check that the credential that you're passing in Drive service is for the same account that the File file is from. Eg. many people make the mistake of generating a credential for a Service Account, and then try to apply it to their own Google Account.